# Print Layout Not showing Properly after Set page settings in rdlc

Tags: rdlc

I creating a report in rdlc in winforms. This is working properly. But after i add the page settings to the report viewer the print layout view not showing properly. Only black dots showing. When i comment the page settings it is working properly.

My report binding coding are below

```
            this.reportViewer1.Width = this.Width - 15;
            this.reportViewer1.Height = this.Height - 15;

            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Report1.rdlc";

            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", CustomerList);
            rds.Value = _deliveryNote.CustomerList;
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

            System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pg = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
            pg.Margins.Top = 100;
            pg.Margins.Bottom = 100;
            pg.Margins.Left = 100;
            pg.Margins.Right = 100;
            pg.Landscape = false;
            System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize size = new PaperSize();
            size.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A4;
            pg.PaperSize = size;
            this.reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(pg);

            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Actually when i setup using report GUI its working. The coding way only not working

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not specified the height and width of the paper. Changing your code as follows will solve your problem:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pg = new PageSettings();
// Set margins
pg.Margins  = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(100, 100, 100, 100);

// Set paper size
pg.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169); // 8.27 in x 11.69 in
pg.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A4; // Before .NET Framework 4.5

// Update report and refresh
this.reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(pg);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

// Switch to print Layout (optional)
this.reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
```

For .NET Framework 4.5 and newer, the RawKind needs to be set as follows. Thanks for pointing out @Tyler Durden.

```
pg.PaperSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A4;
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: For DotNet4.5 `pg.PaperSize.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A4;` worked